# @function v/s @mixin in Sass-lang. Which one to use?

Tags: sass

After searching a lot in difference between @function and @mixin I ended up here.

Is there any advantage of using @mixin over @funcion or vice versa. In what context they'll be different, how to use them interchangeably, please come up with examples.

Comment: I have written an article on the similar lines which might help someone who is looking for depth knowledge https://stackcoder.in/posts/sass-or-scss-mixin-vs-extends-vs-placeholder

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Functions are useful specifically because they *return* values. Mixins are nothing like functions--they usually just provide valuable blocks of code.

Usually, there are cases where you might have to use both.

For example, if I wanted to create a [long-shadow with SASS](http://codepen.io/danieltott/pen/AjKay), I would call a function like so:

```
@function makelongshadow($color) {
  $val: 0px 0px $color;
  @for $i from 1 through 200 {
    $val: #{$val}, #{$i}px #{$i}px #{$color};
  }
  @return $val;
}
```

Which would then be called with this mixin:

```
@mixin longshadow($color) {
  text-shadow: makelongshadow($color);
}
```

Which provides us with the actual code.

That gets included in the element:

```
h1 {
    @include longshadow(darken($color, 5% ));
}
```

Comment: Also, you would use functions to access certain data structures in SASS. So for example, map-get-keys is a function because all it does is return the appropriate keys in a SASS map.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. You can use function in place of every mixing - you just need to return the block of css code with all the rules. The question is when to do it and when you should not do it.

Answer (score 1):

[`@function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) is useful when you want to reuse it on **different CSS properties**.

Example, You have dynamic values that you want to use on both `height` and `min-height`, then using [`@function`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function) is the one you would use:

```css
@function dynamic-height($height, $padding) {
  @return $height + $padding;
}

.foo {
  min-height: dynamic-height(300px, 30px);
}

.bar {
  height: dynamic-height(300px, 30px);
}
```

But if you want to reuse it with **same CSS properties**, then you would use a [`@mixin`](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin):

```css
@mixin dynamic-height($height, $padding) {
  min-height: $height;
  padding: $padding;
}

.foo {
  @include @dynamic-height(300px, 30px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

think of `@mixin` as it is just a `@function` that returns a block of style rules.

also, you can use placeholders (like `%selector`) and `@extend`